# use math.max on variables and display corresponding variables

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have a question with my JavaScript code (I am quite new at this...). I am making a test where I will calculate the score of the participants by using their answers. I have multiple variables where I store these answers. And also the calculation of the score is going ok. Then I have a table with the scores. That is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var row1col1var="Fruit";
var rowicol2var="% of how much I love them";
var applep=34; //result from score calcultaion
var row2col1var="Apple";
var bananasp=65; //result from score calcultaion
var row3col1var="Bananas";
document.write('<center><table width="50%" border="0">');
document.write('<tr align="center"><td>' + row1col1var + '<\/td><td>' + rowicol2var + '<\/td><\/tr>');
document.write('<tr align="center"><td>' + row2col1var + '<\/td><td' + applep + "%" + '<\/td><\/tr>');
document.write('<tr align="center"><td>' + row3col1var + '<\/td><td' + bananasp + "%" +'<\/td><\/tr>'); 
document.write('<\/table><\/center>'); </script>
```

Here I display the results per "fruit" in a table. What I cannot get to work is this:
I want to pick out the best score (in this case 65, for Bananas) and display: "You love Bananas the most." (ie link 65 to Bananas and display Bananas). I was trying to give the cells an id with the name Apples or Bananas and calling on the id to display it, but this did not work.

My problem breaks down in two pieces:
1. I cannot get math.max to work on variables. 
2. I do not know how to link the highest score to its "name" (ie 65 belongs to Bananas).

I hope you can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use more appropriate way for coding. For storing data, you can use object or array. I am using an array for this example.
Check this :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getScore(){
    var scoreArr = [];
    scoreArr.push(['apple', '35']);
    scoreArr.push(['apple', '65']);

    var maxPercentage = null;
    var lovedFruit = '';
    var finalScore = '<center><table width="50%" border="0"><tr align="center"><th>Fruits</th><th>% of how much I love them</th></tr>';

    for (var i = 0; i < scoreArr.length; i++) {
        finalScore += '<tr align="center"><td>' + scoreArr[i][0] + '</td><td>' + scoreArr[i][1] + "%" + '</td></tr>';
        if (maxPercentage === null) {
            lovedFruit = scoreArr[i][0];
            maxPercentage = parseInt(scoreArr[i][1]);
        } else {
            if (maxPercentage < parseInt(scoreArr[i][1])) {
                lovedFruit = scoreArr[i][0];
                maxPercentage = parseInt(scoreArr[i][1]);
            }
        }
    }
    finalScore += '</table><br>Result is : ' + maxPercentage + ' belongs to ' + lovedFruit + '</center>';

   // WITH JAVASCRIPT
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.innerHTML = finalScore;
    document.body.insertBefore(container, null); //append div to end

  // WITH JQUERY
      // $('body').append(finalScore); 

}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad=getScore()>
</body>
</html>
```

It will store your data in array and then you can do whatever you want in more sophisticated way.

Comment: yuk, `$('body')` that's jquery. Making the novice topicstarter having to learn library's while he is grasping javascript itself at the moment. At least inform him that your current code will not simply work by default!!!

Comment: This code will work using JQuery plugin, as $ is supported by JQuery.

Comment: Thank for your answer! But I am not quite sure what you are doing in this code (and it also does not seem to works). Do I need to install something? Is it impossible to let my code work in JavaScript?

Comment: I think, you might need the whole code as you are novice to java script. I am making some changes. I think, you will able to understand it. Use firebug in order to run the flow of execution in java script.